# Sending POST request with form-data works, but its simple raw equivalent doesn't

Tags: http, postman

I am trying to send a Post request to my server, and here is the thing, when I try doing that with "form-data" everything works absolutely fine.
you can see what I wrote below:
[form-data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lYbG.png)

But when I send it as a raw Json, it doesn't work at all...
below is the body that contains the json code:

```
{
"cookie": "test1|1521275188|udWlZft3jKw8HYBmni7F2LzctUFBCSDOzahc63Jm6Gk|2a7f91a7d68e2c10399706ba3f9e2833123ddb17e1de2f2d7a669b47ff701ab0",
"nonce": "84d874e5b7",
"title": "post Try" }
```

as you can see, I wrote a key and a value in both places, but one works and the other doesn't, and because I only sent 3 parameter I don't really see any place for a spelling mistake...
What do you think it might be?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the object too, the form wraps the form-data inside the object
something like,

```
"post":{
{
"cookie": "test1|1521275188|udWlZft3jKw8HYBmni7F2LzctUFBCSDOzahc63Jm6Gk|2a7f91a7d68e2c10399706ba3f9e2833123ddb17e1de2f2d7a669b47ff701ab0",
"nonce": "84d874e5b7",
"title": "post Try" }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some server codes which accepts request

Comment: the form-data works https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lYbG.png . I couldn't write a code that works though...

Comment: I am using Wordpress Rest API